# Upgrading PostgreSQL from 9.6.6 to 10.1

Tags: postgresql, mac-os-x

I'm attempting to upgrade my local instance of postgres to 10.1 (from 9.6.6) on macOS.  Using [this gist](https://gist.github.com/giannisp/ebaca117ac9e44231421f04e7796d5ca) as a guide, I've encountered a problem when running `pg_upgrade`.  Here are the steps taken:

```
$ mv /usr/local/var/postgres /usr/local/var/postgres.old

$ mkdir /usr/local/share/postgresql.old
$ cp -r /usr/local/share/postgresql/timezone /usr/local/share/postgresql.old
$ cp -r /usr/local/share/postgresql/timezonesets /usr/local/share/postgresql.old

$ initdb /usr/local/var/postgres -E utf8

$ pg_upgrade \
  -d /usr/local/var/postgres.old/ \
  -D /usr/local/var/postgres/ \
  -b /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@9.6/9.6.6/bin \
  -B /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/10.1/bin/

Performing Consistency Checks
-----------------------------
Checking cluster versions
Old cluster data and binary directories are from different major versions.
Failure, exiting
```

Prior to this attempted upgrade, 9.6.6 was running perfectly with `/usr/local/var/postgres` as its data directory.  Why does `pg_upgrade` think the old data does not match the old binaries?

**Edit:** Here's the output requested by @jjanes:

```
$ /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@9.6/9.6.6/bin/pg_ctl start -D /usr/local/var/postgres.old
server starting
FATAL:  database files are incompatible with server
DETAIL:  The data directory was initialized by PostgreSQL version 9.5, which is not compatible with this version 9.6.6.
```

I had assumed 9.* was considered the same "major version", as per semver.  Apparently not; upgrading from 9.5.10 worked perfectly.

Comment: Try `/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@9.6/9.6.6/bin/pg_ctl start -D /usr/local/share/postgresql.old` and let us know what error you get.